# Unity 2D Character Too Much Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

Firstly sorry for my bad english. My problem so clear;

My character sometimes jump to very high.

Normally;
[gif; normal jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNKvW.gif)

sometimes this happening if character jump to collider corner;
[gif; anormal high jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAjpN.gif)

Why this happening? How I can fixed this problem?

that's my codes;

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
{
    jumpButton = GameObject.Find("Jump").GetComponent<Button>();
    jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(Jump);

    groundCheck = GameObject.Find("GroundCheck").GetComponent<Transform>();
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    MoveInput = SimpleInput.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(MoveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (isGrounded && jump)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jump = false;
    }
}

public void Jump()
{
    jump = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it, you are able to accelerate your upward movement everytime you jump.

In order to make the jump produce the same velocity each time, just set the y velocity to some value. We can use `jumpForce/rb.mass` to get the same value that using `AddForce` with `ForceMode2D.Impulse` produces.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    jumpButton = GameObject.Find("Jump").GetComponent<Button>();
    jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(Jump);

    groundCheck = GameObject.Find("GroundCheck").GetComponent<Transform>();
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    MoveInput = SimpleInput.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(MoveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (isGrounded && jump)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce/rb.mass);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```